# What is the result if a player has insufficient material and the opponent plays two illegal moves?

Tags: rules, draw, illegal-move, winning

Suppose player X has only a king. Their opponent has played two illegal moves during the game. Is it a draw or does X win?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Draw by §7.5.5. (Analog is fallen flag, draw by §6.9.)

> 7.5.5    ...However, the game is drawn if the
> position is such that the opponent cannot checkmate the player’s king
> by any possible series of legal moves.  (Source: [FIDE Laws of Chess](https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012023))

Comment: The laws being referred to are at https://handbook.fide.com/chapter/E012023 . The relevant text in 7.5.5 is "However, the game is drawn if the position is such that the opponent cannot checkmate the player’s king by any possible series of legal moves."